# Find Unique Values in two data based on Date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am trying to find two unique names in two data based on Date. Could you kindly advise what formula can be used? Thank you so much

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HKnESOUKjh4cfVFCLwQkET3Z0F7LCE5X3F9492IKwCI/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: did you try UNIQUE()? your question is not clear.  Why those names that are highlighted?

Comment: Because I want someone who is look at this question can locate the unique names easily. Could you give an example how to unique() with Date.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell H12 I entered

```
=query(query({A2:B; D3:E}, "Select Col1, Col2, count(Col2) where Col2 <>'' group by Col1, Col2", 1), "Select Col1, Col2 where Col3 = 1",1)
```

See if that works for you?

Comment: Thank you JPV.  This is exactly what I am looking for.